# Rails change_column error: Mysql2::Error: COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm in the process of upgrading our Rails application from 5.2.3 to 7.0.3. A migration that worked with the older rails is failing with the new one.

This is the migration:

```
change_column :documents, :override, :json, using: 'override::JSON'
```

which results in the error:

```
Mysql2::Error: COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary'
```

I'd like to know where the 'binary' is coming from.

I've tried:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

but it does not help.

Doing "show variables like '%char%'; show variables like '%coll%';" results in:

```
| character_set_client     | utf8                                      |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                      |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                      |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                    |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                      |
| character_set_server     | latin1                                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                      |
| character_sets_dir       | /rdsdbbin/mysql-5.7.38.R1/share/charsets/ |
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_database   | utf8_unicode_ci   |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
```

The database is in AWS RDS (MySQL Community).

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error in rails 7 when I tried to change the column data type from text to JSON

I defined that the collation was nil in the migration

For Example:

```
change_column :documents, :override, :json, collation: nil
```